# If the user already logged in then the first tab will hide and directly jump to the second tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a tab section without using Jquery UI. Now I have to set some condition on it.

1) If the user already logged in then the first tab will hide and directly jump to the second tab.

2) I have to disabled next tab until and unless the user does not field all the details in the current tab content.

Would you help me in this?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_target a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active_tab");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active_tab");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab_inside").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```css
 body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .tab_section{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .tab_section ul.tab_target{
position: relative;
display: block;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
clear: both;
/*background: #f8f8f8;*/
}
.tab_section ul.tab_target li{
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
}
.tab_section ul.tab_target li a{
  padding: 06px 45px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
text-decoration: none;
}
.tab_section ul.tab_target li a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00a63f;
}

.border{

border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.tab_inside
{
padding: 20px 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: none;
}
.tab_inside form .text-fields{
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.tab_target li.active_tab {
position: relative;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 z-index: 5;
}

#tab1 {
 display: block;   
}
.all_tab {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php session_start(); ?>
    <div class="tab_section">
          <ul  class="tab_target">
            <li class="active_tab"><a href="#tab1">Demo1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Demo2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Demo3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">Demo4</a></li>
          </ul>
    <div class="all_tab">
      <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {?>
    <div id="tab1" class="border tab_inside">
      <h2>Demo1</h2>
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="text-fields">
        <label>username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="text-fields">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    </div><!--tab1-->
    <?php
    } ?>

      <div id="tab2" class="border tab_inside hide_tab">
        <h2>Demo2</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="text-fields">
          <label>Email </label>
          <input type="email" name="email">
          </div>

          <div class="text-fields">
          <label>Mobile no</label>
          <input type="text" name="mobile">
          </div>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
      </div><!--tab2-->



      <div id="tab3" class="border tab_inside">
        <h2>Demo3</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="text-fields">
          <label>Address</label>
                <textarea name="address"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="text-fields">
          <label>Address2</label>
          <textarea name="address2"></textarea>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
      </div><!--tab4-->


      <div id="tab4" class="border tab_inside">
        <h2>Demo4</h2>
        
    <h2>Success</h2>
      </div><!--tab4-->

    </div><!--all_tab-->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me i will use php direct jump to second tab

or u can set a var in js by php to control jump or not jump

not sure help or not

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can I use to directly on the second tab if the user logged in? If not logged in then it will display the first tab

Comment: php check >echo"<script>"; if( isset (session........)) { echo"var log='true'"} else {echo"var log="false""} echo"</script>";  << if u use this way u need to check id that set in session on the next tab else some user will chg the js code . if u load all page when onload u no need to check the session on next page

Answer (score 0):

if u load all the page together

```
<?php 
    $session=2;// example of session data value
?>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{ 
    $("[name='dv']").css("display","none");

    <?php 
    if(isset($session))
        echo"$('#d2').css('display','');";  
    else
        echo"$('#d1').css('display','');";
    ?>
});
</script>

<form>
<div id="d1" name="dv">
    reg page
</div>
<div id="d2" name="dv">
    tab 2
</div>
</form>
```

if u load the page one by one

```
<?php 
    $session=2;// example of session data value
?>

<form>
<?php if(isset($session))
{?>
<div id="d1" name="dv">
    reg page
</div>
<?php }
else
{
?>
<div id="d2" name="dv">
    tab 2
</div>
<?php }?>
</form>
```

not sure what u want , sorry

my English is too poor

Comment: I am using TAB, If session is not set than it will display the only reg page and I need all the tab. If session set then display from second tab and first will also display but as a hidden